# issue with removing google map instance from dom in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I am writing a web app using react. I can successfully load the map instance by using refs:

```
        return <div className="map_component" ref={this.loadMapOnScreen}></div>;
```

and in the loadMapOnScreen function I am loading the map

```
    private loadMapOnScreen = (e) => {
        let map = new google.maps.Map(e, {
            center: {lat: pos.lat, lng: pos.lng},
            zoom: 16
        });
        this.setState({map: map}); }
```

but the problem is that when I am changing the state, I can't remove the map instance from the DOM. Style of the "map_component" removes successfully from the page, but the map instance reamins.

Comment: Have a function `killMap = () => {this.setState({map: null}); }`

Comment: I am actually doing it in my load mapOnScreen, because it's being called even when the component is unmounting, so I check there if to see I am leaving and setting the map state to null but it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, based on your code, it looks like you aren't setting it to null in loadMapOnScreen... Please post code where you are setting it to null. I don't think doing it in componentWillUnmount is a good idea either because it's redundant code. If the user leaves (componentWillUnmount), the map will get wiped out from the state already. What you want is to hide the map in a certain condition. Try putting it in a button and see if that works.

Comment: private loadMapOnScreen = (e) => {
        if(this.state.viewType == ViewType.List) {
            this.setState({map:null});
        } else {
            let map = new google.maps.Map(e, {
                center: {lat: pos.lat, lng: pos.lng},
                zoom: 16
            });
            this.setState({map: map});
    }

Comment: `console.log()` is a handy function for debugging when your program doesn't work as expected. Try logging the viewType and see if it ever goes to the path where the map is set to null.